# 150A for outdoors kitchen - wire size

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, conduit, aluminum-wiring

I am working with the city to get the permits to build an outdoors kitchen with its own sub-panel. I decided to place it 100ft from the house. In my list[*] I have an electric tankless water heater, an induction range and a hot-tub/spa (all 240V), plus a bunch of occasional 120V devices (food processor etc) and LED lights. After some research on those loads I want to size the wiring for 150A, the great majority of which will be 240V loads.

So far my plan includes 2in sch40 PVC conduit to house the wiring in the trench. How do I calculate the (aluminum) wiring size and what cable is appropriate for buried conduit? Thank you

[*] The comments asked to provide a list of my desired loads for this load center as to validate my requirements. Keep in mind this outdoors kitchen is designed to feed parties of 40 people:

- Induction cooktop https://products.geappliances.com/appliance/gea-specs/PHP9036BMTS 50A@240VAC
- Water heater 18kW 2x40A@240VAC [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0047V0KSU](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0047V0KSU)
  The water heater might be oversized but it needs to provide hot water to two large sinks, a dishwasher and a shower next to the pool. Maybe the smaller 11kW 60A@240VAC will work but I do not want to be limited by the wiring.
- Hot-tub/SPA. I have not chosen the right model yet but one that might fit is: https://www.wayfair.com/outdoor/pdp/futura-spas-8-person-88-jet-hot-tub-with-stainless-jets-and-waterfall-futr1000.html 50A@220VAC
- permanent 120V loads: dishwasher, refrigerator, ice machine, roof mount duct fan, lighting
- a dozen of 20A outlets for occasional devices

Comment: It would be good if answers discussed the neutral size, and under what conditions it would be permissible to downsize the neutral.

Comment: Can you post the rated wattage/amperage for the spa, heater, and range?  Also, how many amps is your main service? (That second water heater has me concerned some...)

Comment: A point of use water heater I use for cases like this is only 30a 240v it brings water up to 135/140 degrees for a single tap with moderate flow. But I agree we need the sizes to calculate the feeder even with a spa it sounds like the op just added the sizes with no derating as may be allowed.

Comment: The question is about how to size the *wiring* for a 150A sub-panel and how to choose the correct cable for buried conduit outdoors. I am impressed by all your reputation on this website and by the answer you have given on other questions and I'll be happy to provide all the details you wish however it's going to take me some time to gather all the details and write them up.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica yes that is exactly why I specified the big part of the load would be on 240V

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel fair, but is it really relevant to this question what my current service is? As long as I protect my new wiring with a breaker that is appropriate for its size.

Comment: @EdBeal regarding to the water heater power, I want to make sure that if my current choice of heater for the sink (this kitchen will have two, plus a shower, detail that I did not put in earlier) I can get a more powerful one without being limited by the wiring size.

Comment: @AlessioSangalli you have to run the load calculations recursively, all the way up to the service, every time you do a load calculation -- imagine what'd happen if you had a 200A service trying to service this big kitchen feeder + an entire all-electric house with stuff going as well...

Comment: We cannot tell as you have not provided any info at this point I would say no you cannot because your main service panel is two small. the sub  may also be two small for the devices I might install , it makes no difference if it is 110 or 240 we need the wattages I think you have been asked this 3 times,      Your question sounds like can I boost the horsepower of my car to 500hp  I have a blower and extra wide wrinkle wall tires with a cool paint job.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel "imagine what'd happen if you had a 200A service trying to service this..." I imagine the upstream breaker would pop open if the sum of the loads go over the rating.

Comment: @EdBeal I do not know the details of the code (hence my question on this forum) but in my industry, the only important parameter in providing a power transmissin line protection is the rating of the wiring (that include things like material, temperature, installation method derating etc), not what the loads are or what the source is capable of.

Comment: This said, as I mentioned earlier I need more time to collect all the information about the choices I made. It's going to take quite a bit of writing, probably a couple of days. I need to research and use the correct terminology, for example I will not connect this to a panel inside the house, as my "main" switch is outdoors next to the meter.
I appreciate that you ask me to perform my due duty in explaining the problem, just give me enough time to do it properly :)

Comment: @AlessioSangalli -- yeah, what size is that main breaker? (And indeed, the upstream breaker would trip, but you don't want to be nuisance tripping the breaker repeatedly either, for both your sake and the breaker's)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel the main breaker is a 200A and I am actively working with the city and power company to upgrade it to 400A. I have the appointment tomorrow morning. There will be a meter / panel combo that will go to different load centers, including one in this outdoors kitchen. I wish I had three phase power for the workshop where I have the mill and lathe, but I'll have to continue with single phase VFD's. As that part of the job is actively being worked on, I was trying not to bring it in the discussion.

Comment: @AlessioSangalli -- got it. Can you provide makes and models for the various appliances that are going in this kitchen?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I did above. This kitchen will be built in the spring and you are asking me to anticipate elements that have not been acquired yet - but they will be very similar to the ones listed.

Comment: @AlessioSangalli -- can you find information on the *nameplate wattage* of that spa you linked, or a different representative spa? (We'll need the actual nameplate wattage to figure out if your 150A ballpark figure for the feeder is correct or not)

Comment: Can you explain the underlying issue you are trying to uncover here? Are you concerned this line is too big or too small? Most any hot tub I've seen claims 50 or 60A @220-240VAC, I am really confused by why the question on how to size a 150A rated line according to code cannot be taken as is. Today I had a misunderstanding with the power company and the appointment was rescheduled :(

Comment: @AlessioSangalli -- possibly either.  Also, when you say "washing machine", you're referring to a dishwasher, right?

Comment: What NEC edition does your locality use? (This is actually quite important, as there was a code change in 2017 that severely impacts your plans)

Comment: Good, I'll ask that

Comment: 2016 California Electrical Code which itself is based on the 2014 NEC. However it is in my best interest implement the state of the art and I'd like to know the difference between the two. If I may ask a favor, I prefer general principles and references to the code instead of spoon feeding. I have read some other answers you have made including: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/129784/need-help-choosing-wire-for-a-detached-garage that I put in my bookmarks.
PS I work with half megawatt VFD loads at work, so I do not think I lack the theoretical and physics grounds for this job.